# Can a target group have more than one asg in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-alb

I want a target group for an alb to be able to add a second asg. This is that so it can slowly replace the current asg.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: So far it seems to have worked, but pretty early in developing and actually testing. Was seeing if someone did something similar. I’ll answer my own question here when I’m 100% done.